# Hight First Input Delay (FID) measure on an empty page. (No js, no css)

Tags: html, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to improve the FID measure for my wordpress website with no success.

Whatever I do the "pagespeed insights" tool shows FID over 100ms on the Mobile tab.

The desktop tab shows ~4ms.

Finally I have just created an html file with 1 line of text no js, no css, just a single line of text.

I have uploaded the file to the same server and the FID is still over 100ms on Mobile.
How can it be?

https://www.extra.co.il/wp-content/themes/extra/test.html

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=iw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.extra.co.il%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fextra%2Ftest.html

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. So is for specific coding issues not network issues or explenation on how networks work. There multiple reasons why mobile devices can take longer. None of that has to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

**Origin Summary** is taken over a 28 day rolling average across every page on the site.

Simply uploading a test file will not change that as it is based on **real world data** and is not part of the synthetic test.

In the "Lab" section (the synthetic test) you will see "Total Blocking Time", that is the equivalent metric for First Input Delay and you will see it is at 0ms (as there is no JavaScript blocking your test page).

The reason the desktop performs better is down to processing power, mobile phones typically run 2x-8x times slower than a desktop CPU so it is expected that the First Input Delay is going to be higher on mobile.

Yet again that is real world data on a 28 day rolling average so you can't make a change today and see the results immediately.

For this reason I would suggest using [the web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) to gather real world data in real time rather than relying on the data coming from the CrUX dataset (which is what Page Speed Insights is using to display the "Origin Summary".